# Carrying on row auto-number in auto added rows in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, I have created a Excel Ribbon built in XML and have a module linked to this on the Increase Rows button this calls a Public Sub and increase's the rows required.

```
Public Sub IncreaseRows(control As IRibbonControl)
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCount As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

iCount = Application.InputBox("How many rows do you 
want to add?", "Add Rows")
If iCount = 0 Then Exit Sub

iRow = Application.InputBox("Enter row number the 
grey-line is on", "Row Number")
If iRow = 0 Then Exit Sub

For i = 1 To iCount
Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Insert
Next i
End Sub
```

This works perfectly but i would like to also carry on the auto increment in column A once the new rows are add this can be from 5 to 100+ so you have a better understanding i have a screenshot to help.[image]

I have written several pieces of code to try to achieve this with no luck can anyone assist please.

Comment: share you "pieces of code" so we can try to correct them.

Comment: I will get this done later today to achieve my goal i have drawn up these steps;
1) Insert cells from Icount
2) Get cell address of (A-F) draw boarder around cells to mach current boarder
3) Get last row-data
4) Fill (A) with auto increment of last number in cell(A) in row inserted cells in step 1